ParseException : Unable to create iceberg branch
I followed following iceberg documentation to create the branch for staging the data and quality check. I am using jupyter notebook with following configurations:
https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-ddl/#branching-and-tagging-ddl
%%configure  { "--conf": "spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions --conf spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog --conf spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.warehouse=s3://bucket-name/warehouse/ --conf spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.catalog-impl=org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog --conf spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.io-impl=org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO", "--datalake-formats": "iceberg", "--enable-metrics": "true", "--enable-spark-ui": "true", "--enable-job-insights": "true", "--enable-glue-datacatalog": "true", "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": "true", "--enable-spark-ui": "true",  "--spark-event-logs-path": "s3://bucket-name/sparkui/" }
Table DDL  :
CREATE TABLE <catalog>.<db>.<target_table>
USING iceberg
TBLPROPERTIES('format-version'='2')
AS SELECT * FROM <source_table>

ALTER TABLE <catalog>.<db>.<target_table> SET TBLPROPERTIES (
    'write.wap.enabled'
);


+-------------------+-------------------+
|                key|              value|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|current-snapshot-id|6707933859773686092|
|             format|    iceberg/parquet|
|     format-version|                  2|
|  write.wap.enabled|               true|
+-------------------+-------------------+

When I run following statement it keeps running into error:
spark.sql("alter table <catalog>.<db>.<target_table> create BRANCH audit_branch") 
Error:

ParseException: 
Syntax error at or near 'create'(line 1, pos 64)

== SQL ==
alter table <catalog>.<db>.<target_table>  create BRANCH audit_branch
----------------------------------------------------------------^^^


I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, can someone suggest what am I missing?
I tried steps in the documentation - https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-ddl/#branching-and-tagging-ddl

Have you tried including jar packages? Mine works with
"spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.5.2,org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-aws-bundle:1.5.2"

I am using spark 3.5.1
